# LINQ to XML recursively remove elements - C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Root>
 <Section name="xyz" />
 <Section name="abc">
   <Section name="def" />
 </Section>
 <Section name="abc">
   <Section name="def">
     <Section name="xyz" />
     <Section name="abc" />
     <Section name="xyz">
       <Section name="xyz" />
     </Section>
  </Section>
</Section>
</Root>
```

I have the `XDocument` representation of the XML. How I do traverse through the tree and remove all elements with say `abc`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's really easy :)

```
doc.Descendants("Section")
   .Where(x => (string) x.Attribute("name") == "xyz")
   .Remove();
```

Gotta love LINQ to XML...

EDIT: I've just tried it with your sample XML, and this was the result afterwards:

```
<Root>
  <Section name="abc">
    <Section name="def" />
  </Section>
  <Section name="abc">
    <Section name="def">
      <Section name="abc" />
    </Section>
  </Section>
</Root>
```

Please let me know if that's not what you were expecting.

Comment: When Jon Skeet answers, I don't even have to verify :) Thanks Jon!

Comment: By the way, I assume I can use `Descendants` in a join condition as well? Something like `var j = from h in doc.Descendants("Section") join k in anotherDoc.Descendants("ElementName") on ..`

Comment: @Nick: Absolutely. It just returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>`.